# how can I split an image at flex application

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, bitmap

how can I split this image in flex application.
in fact I'm thinking  to call an image from xml and split it  at " flex application"

I tried a few methods.but  it doesn't work!
I'll  glad for your help.

```
 <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"  initialize="image_loader_completeHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;


        protected function image_loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, leftpart);
            loader.load( new URLRequest("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/images/image1.jpg"));



            function leftpart(e:Event):void 
            {


                var bmpd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData    (loader.width/2,loader.height,false)

                bmpd1.draw(loader,null,null,null,rec);

                var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle   (0,0,bmpd1.width,bmpd1.height);

                var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap (bmpd1);


                image_loader.addChild(bmp);

            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:Image id="image_loader"   />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only half of the one should appear"? Only half of the picture?

Comment: Explaining what you already tried--and why it didn't work--can a great help to us helping you.

Comment: @Lance Roberts You're title edit made the title much more confusing than it was; so I took a chance at re-editing it.  Good work on the question text, though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, it actually wasn't my title edit, just approving a suggested edit (to which I did make changes).  I'm fine with your change.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com The title doesn't really make much sense either now. "How can I add part of url image" would mean what? To add part of a string containing the url? To add part of the image?

Comment: Sorry Lance; I missed the other name in the edit history.  @BujancaMihai The title is more consistent with the question text now. I hope the original poster clarifies.  The title "How can I add AS3 code to Flex" is like asking "how can I add Java to this Android Application" or "How can I add water to this puddle".

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I suggested another edit, because I think it makes the question clearer, so now there can be no doubt if the user wants part of the url or part of the image. BTW to be honest, I am not sure yet what the user wants. The only question is "How can I use this as3 code in flex". I suppose that means "where to put it in my flex code" or something like that.

Comment: Yall are editing the OP's wording without being sure what the actual question is?  O.o

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the bitmap to the image element, simply set the bitmapData as the source:

```
function leftpart(e:Event):void 
{
    var bmpd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData    (loader.width/2,loader.height,false)
    bmpd1.draw(loader);
    image_loader.source = bmpd1;
}
```

You don't even have to create a `Bitmap` object as `source` accepts `BitmapData`

Comment: marcela god bless you, Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as the answer. Thanks.